# Create Single Line Item, No Fixed Widths

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to build out an HTML/CSS structure that would produce something like the image I have attached. I'm looking to develop a container that houses a variable number of inline-elements with only one of those elements filling what the other inline elements don't.

I've seen a few solutions floating around but they always seem to deal with fixed-width elements then the one that fills the remaining space is set to 99%. I've asked this question before (and just now removed the post) and I hope this post better explains what I want to do. I'm really looking for a no JavaScript fix so I can apply this anywhere without having to luge code around with me as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/FF3LJ/1/

The 0's are there to represent varied widths.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="float-left">000</div>
    <div class="float-right">00000000</div>
    <div class="float-right">0</div>
    <div class="fill-the-void">
        <span>Lorem ipsum lkasdgj dlagkjas dglkajsd glaskdjgasdgk lksadgjalskdgj lkj</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="float-left">0000000000</div>
    <div class="float-right">000</div>
    <div class="float-right">00000</div>
    <div class="fill-the-void">
       <span>Lorem ipsum lkasdgj dlagkjas dglkajsd glaskdjgasdgk lksadgjalskdgj lkj</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="float-left">0</div>
    <div class="float-right">0000000000</div>
    <div class="float-right">0</div>
    <div class="fill-the-void">
        <span>Lorem ipsum lkasdgj dlagkjas dglkajsd glaskdjgasdgk lksadgjalskdgj lkj</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
li { height:20px; margin:0 0 10px; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
li div { height:20px; background:#fff; }
.float-left { background:#f93; float:left; margin-right:5px; }
.float-right { background:#f93; float:right; margin-left:5px; }
.fill-the-void { text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; }
.fill-the-void span { background:#f3c; }
```

Comment: This works very beautifully, and points for replicating the colors (I used them for visual indication, I'm not really using them :). My concern is that this approach is a bit hard to teach. I'd like the developers using this code to be able to put in their "columns" in order and not have to worry about adding float classes, but that just might not be possible with CSS.

Comment: I think you underestimate your developers! :) I don't see a way to do this without floats, however since floating is CSS, I would imagine re-naming classes to match what the content actually is would make it much easier for anyone to understand. Developers just need to know the html structure, which is a given for any development. example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyW94/1/

Comment: I've had a few hours to stew over this, and what you're saying echoes what I've been thinking. A lot of our developers are great with WPF/XAML where things like this aren't an issue so I'm trying to simplify things as much as I can. Unfortunately, CSS presents a challenge representing what I posted in logical order. Your examples are beautiful and you did a really great job presenting a solution. I wish I could give you more reputation than upvoting and checking this as correct. Thanks for the help, and for the sake of the community please continue to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could just set the width of each orange element using percentages according to how much space they need to take up.  When you add an element, just decrease the percentage of space it takes up.  The purple element will fill up the rest of the space.  See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2qUK/

In this case, the width of the container is set to `100%`, but you could adjust this based on your needs.

Comment: The thing is, I wouldn't know the percentages. It might vary item to item, and case-to-case. I'd like to make this as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS, I think the best you can do is overflow the text on one line. **[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aW7Ba/1/)**.

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.thumbnail { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.content {
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Ut auctor enim et, magna purus augue magna placerat placerat aliquam cum enim tortor nunc amet nisi urna, ac porta urna auctor in dignissim, aenean mus turpis augue ridiculus dictumst non mus, mattis, turpis, sociis aliquam. Eros sed aliquet, porta! 
    </div>
</div>
```